# Compute the $\pi_{1} (S^{3} /G)$ and $H_{m} ( S^{3} / G)$ for the following $G$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, quotient-spaces, fundamental-groups

I am studying for a qualying exam and there is one exercise from the previous years exams which I don't know how to approach.

Let $n$ be a positive integer and
$$
G = \{ g \in \Bbb C^{\times} | g^{n} =1 \}
$$
the group of the $n$-roots of unity. The group $G$ acts by multiplication on the sphere
$$
S^{3} = \{ a + bi +cj+dk \in \mathbb{H} \: | \: a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}=1 \} \subset \mathbb{H}  = \{ a+bi+cj+dk | a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \}
$$
seen as subset of quaternions $\mathbb{H}$. Let $X = S^{3} / G $ be the quotient space. Compute the fundamental group $ \pi_{1} (X, x_{0})$ respect an arbitrary base point $x_{0} \in X$, and the homology groups $H_{m} ( X , \mathbb{Z} )$ for all $m$.

I have found this post:

[Calculate the homology group of $S^3/G$, an Harvard qualifying exam problem with "unclear" solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351303/calculate-the-homology-group-of-s3-g-an-harvard-qualifying-exam-problem-with)

But I don't know what is Stiefel-Whitney class.

I don't know how to attack this problem, if my intuition with $S^{2}$ serves me on something, this space is a $n$ folded version of $S^{3}$, so we can probably expect groups with nonzero torsion. But I don't know how to procced. I have studied Hatcher's chapters 1 and 2, and Rotman's chapters 1-5, is there any way to solve this using that knowledge? Or should I learn additional material?

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned Stiefel-Whitney classes, but computing $\pi_1(S^3/G)$ is done in 1 line if you know the theory of the deck transformation group of a universal covering map.

Comment: I mentioned them because the answer to the problem (which was a bit different, as $G$ was not the same) mentioned them. But I don't know what they are.

Comment: About $ \pi_{1} ( S^{3} / G )$, the universal covering space should be $S^{3}$ as it's simply connected, $ \pi_{1} ( S^{3} )$ is trivial so by theorem 54.6 (b) of munkres, the group should be of order $n$ as $S^{3}$ folds $n$ times on $S^{3} / G$.
More useful seems corollary 81.4 of Munkres, as $S^{3}$ is simply connected $\mathcal{C} ( S^{3}, p , S^{3} /G)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_{1} ( S^{3} /G, x_{0})$. And I guess that all the elements on $\mathcal{C} ( S^{3}, p , S^{3} /G)$ are given by $x -> g^{i}x$ so it's the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: In that case the only answer that I can suggest is: learn the theory of fundamental groups and covering spaces and deck transformation groups. That's a significant fraction of a first year algebraic topology course, and giving a tutorial here to answer your question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to add that I also studied Munkres book. I am a little rusty on the algebraic topology part of it, but I should re-study it. Sorry, I focused so much on homology part that I forget that I should be able to solve the fundamental group part with the theory which my courses covered.

Answer (score 4):

$G$ is finite group that acts freely on $S^3$. Because $S^3$ is simply connected, $\pi_1(S^3/G)\cong G\cong \Bbb Z/n$. (Since each element in $G$ represents a rotatation (homeomorphism) of a Hausdorff space, that $G$ acts freely on $S^3$ implies proper discontinuity, so you can apply proposition 1.40 in Hatcher, which you have studied.)

---

Now, we compute the integral homology groups.

- We have $H_0(S^3/G)\cong \Bbb Z$ by connectedness and $H_1(S^3/G)\cong\pi_1(S^3/G)\cong \Bbb Z/n$ by abelianization.

We would like to use Poincare duality to obtain the information of other homology groups. To do so, we need to check the orientability first. Since the action is free, we know that $S^3/G$ is a spherical manifold, which is orientable.

- Orientability implies that $H_3(S^3/G)\cong \Bbb Z$.
- We know that $$H_2(S^3/G)\cong H^1(S^3/G)\cong\operatorname{Hom}(H_1(S^3/G),\Bbb Z)\oplus \operatorname{Ext}(H_0(S^3/G),\Bbb Z)\cong 0$$ by Poincare duality and Universal Coefficient Theorem.

In conclusion,
$$H_k(S^3/G;\Bbb Z)\cong\begin{cases}\Bbb Z & k=0,3\\ \Bbb Z/n & k=1\\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

---

To see that the action of $G$ on $S^3$ is free. We may identify $\Bbb H$ with $\Bbb R^4$ and elements in $G$ with matrices. Suppose $h\cdot x=x$ for some $h=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\in G$ and $x=a+bi+cj+dk\in S^3\subset\Bbb H$ ($x$ will be identified with $\vec{x}=(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb R^4$), then
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta & -\sin\theta & 0 & 0\\
\sin\theta & \cos\theta & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\
0 & 0 & \sin\theta & \cos\theta \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta\\
a\sin\theta+b\cos\theta\\
c\cos\theta-d\sin\theta\\
c\sin\theta+d\cos\theta
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
($h$ is identified with the $4\times 4$ matrix) This shows that $\vec{x}=(a,b,c,d)$ is an eigenvector, and $1$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to $\vec{x}$. By direct computation, the characteristic polynomial of the matrix is
$$((\cos\theta-\lambda)^2+\sin^2\theta)^2$$
Since $\lambda=1$ is a root, we have $$(\cos\theta-1)^2+\sin^2\theta=0$$
It's a sum of two squares, so we have $\sin\theta=0$ and $\cos\theta=1$, which proves that $h=1\in G$. Hence, the action is free.